# What is JaMP and how can I learn about it?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

In a project, I was asked to achieve shared-memory parallelization in Java, by the means of `JaMP`, which extends Java for OpenMP. I am almost a complete beginner in the domain, and after 10 minutes of searching, the internet didn't prove itself highly helpful.

My main question: is `JaMP` a linux-only implementation? And if not, what is good starting-point to start learning?

Answer (score 3):

JaMP (also know as ClusterJaMP) was a research project published in 2007 in the [paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/1298358.1298365) "JaMP: An Implementation of OpenMP for a Java DSM" with the following abstract:

> Although OpenMP is a widely agreed-upon standard for the C/C++ and
> Fortran programming languages for the semi-automatic parallelization
> of programs for shared memory machines, not much has been done on the
> binding of OpenMP to Java that targets clusters with distributed
> memory. This paper presents three major contributions: (1) JaMP is an
> adaptation of the OpenMP standard to Java that implements a large
> subset of the OpenMP specification with an expressiveness comparable
> to that of OpenMP; (2) we suggest a set of extensions that allow a
> better integration of OpenMP into the Java language; (3) we present
> our prototype implementation of JaMP in the research compiler Jackal,
> a software-based distributed shared memory implementation for Java. We
> evaluate the performance of JaMP with a set of micro-benchmarks and
> with OpenMP versions of the parallel Java Grande Forum (JGF)
> benchmarks. The micro-benchmarks show that OpenMP for Java can be
> implemented without much overhead. The JGF benchmarks achieve a good
> speed-up of 5–8 on eight nodes. Copyright © 2007 John Wiley & Sons,
> Ltd.

JaMP implemented in Java some of the functionality of OpenMP 2.0, namely:

- parallel regions;
- *private*, *first private*, and *shared* data-access clauses;
- parallel *for* with the schedule *static*, *guided* and *dynamic*;
- sections;
- single;
- master;
- barriers;
- support of reductions.

Besides supporting the shared-memory paradigm JaMP also extended it further  to complement clusters (distributed-memory paradigm). For the latter, JaMP relied upon the research compiler [Jackal](https://research.vu.nl/en/publications/jackal-a-compiler-supported-fine-grained-distributed-shared-memor).

Instead of pragmas as in `OpenMP`, the parallel constructors in JaMP were expressed using normal Java comments:

```
int count = 0;
//#pragma jamp parallel
{
    //pragma jamp for reduction (+:count)
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
       // some work.
}
```

The syntax of those Java comments mimicked as much as possible the syntax used by OpenMP. During a pre-compilation phase, JaMP would read, and replaced, those comments with the corresponded code that implement the parallel directives.

Comment: Well said. Nothing more to add. :-)

Comment: Thanks :D, I couldn't have had a better seal of approval.